# How do I compute this integrals and conclude that Fubinis theorem doesn't hold everywhere?

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have the following problem:

> Let $\Omega_1=\Omega_2=\mathbb{N}$, $A_1=A_2$ the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ $\mu_1,\mu_2$ the counting measure. We consider the function $$f:\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ where $f(m,n)=1$ if $m=n$, $f(m,n)=-1$ if $m=n+1$ and otherwise 0. I need to compute the following integrals: $$\int_{\Omega_1}\left(\int_{\Omega_2} f\,d\mu_2\right)d\mu_1\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\int_{\Omega_2}\left(\int_{\Omega_1} f\,d\mu_1\right)d\mu_2$$

I first wanted to compute $\int_{\Omega_1}\left(\int_{\Omega_2} f\,d\mu_2\right)d\mu_1$. Since f depends on $(m,n)$ we need to fix $m\in \mathbb{N}$ then $$\int_\mathbb{N} f(m,n)\,\,d\mu_2=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} f(m,n) \mu_2(f^{-1}(\{f(m,n)\}))=-\mu_2(f^{-1}(\{f(m,m-1)\}))+\mu_2(f^{-1}(\{f(m,m)\}))=-\mu_2(f^{-1}(\{-1\}))+\mu_2(f^{-1}(\{1\}))$$

But I somhow don't know how to procede of if this is correct like this. Maybe someone could help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Note that  $\mu_1=\mu_2$ the counting measure. So
$$ \int_\mathbb N f(m,n)\,d\mu_2(n) = f(m,m)+f(m,m-1) = 0$$
if $m>0$ and else the integral is $f(0,0)=1$.

The other integral evaluates to
$$ \int_\mathbb N f(m,n)\,d\mu_1(m) = f(n,n) + f(n+1,n) = 0$$
for *all* $n\in\mathbb N$.

So
$$ \int_\mathbb N \int_\mathbb N f(m,n)\,d\mu_2(n)\,d\mu_1(m) = 1$$
but
$$ \int_\mathbb N \int_\mathbb N f(m,n)\,d\mu_1(m)\,d\mu_2(n) = 0$$

Comment: sorry I don't see how you can go from the integral to $f(m,m)-f(m,m-1)$ isn't the integral of a simple function defined as the sum I wrote above? Could you maybe explain this to me in more detail, because I also don't see where your note is useful. Sorry for the stupid questions

Comment: @Wave If you don't know what "counting measure" is then that should be the first question you ask when you're given a problem about counting measure.

Comment: So we only had that if a set is finite then the counting measure of this set is exaclty the cardinality of the set, otherwise it is infinite. But also with this information I don't see it, isn't my sum correct from above?

Comment: Note that for any given point $m$ there is exactly one $n$ (which is $n=m$) so that $f(m,n)=1$ and only if $m>0$ there is exactly one point $n=m-1$ so that $f(m,n)=-1$. What is the counting measure of a one-element set?

Comment: But of course I messed up, it’s of course $f(m,m)+f(m,m-1$. I accidentally carried the sign from $f(m,m-1)$ into the operation ...

Comment: Is the counting measure of a one element set 1 right? I think I am on the right way understanding this, but is there a way that we can show rigorously, so with the definition of an integral over a simple function that this integral is equal to $f(m,m)+f(m,m-1)$?

Comment: In fact for any $m$ we have that $f(m,.) = \chi_{\{m\}} - \chi_{\{m-1\}}$ is a simple function.

Comment: Ah okei this makes sense so now I only have one remaining question, we get that $\int_\mathbb{N} f(m,n) \,\,\,d\mu_2(n)=0$ then we only need to compute $\int_\mathbb{N} 0\,\,\, d\mu_1(m)$ but why is this $1$? Because on both integrals the inner one is zero in your comutation, then the outher one is exactly the same how can they then be different?

Comment: The first one is $0$ for $m>0$ and $1$ for $m=0$. The other one is $0$ for all $n$. Basically the idea is that you have a reordering of a bad mannered series. For the $\int \,d\mu_1\,d\mu_2$ you take $1-1+1-1+1-1\ldots$ and group this $(1-1)+(1-1)+\ldots = 0$. But for the other integral you take $1+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\ldots = 1$. It is one of the bad mannered properties of infinity.

Comment: Sorry I'm really lost, so we first compute the integral for $m>0$ then $\int_\mathbb{N} f(m,n)d\mu_2=0$ then we need to compute $\int_\mathbb{N} 0d\mu_1$ but we know that $\int_\mathbb{N} 0 d\mu_{1,2}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}0$ but this sum is not 1. Could you maybe explain it in more detail, I'm really stuck and have to much informations, which I can't handle

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I'm looking to this exercise for soooooooo long, and I don't see why your thinking steps follows, it would help to have a detailled explenation because I also don't see why we have so many 1 and -1 ect. I'm really really sorry but I want to understand this

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have it now, but it would still be helpfull to have your explanation to compare it, but is it right if we assume $0$ not to be in $\mathbb{N}$ them both integrals would be equal?

Comment: No, because if we start the natural numbers at $1$, the first integral is $0$ exactly for all $m>1$ and $1$ for $m=1$. The point is that if $m$ is the smallest natural number then there is no $n$ with $n=m-1$, so there is no point with $f(m,n)=-1$.

Comment: ah, this makes sense sorry i didn't see that